# iPhone app simple calculator - objective c error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

i'm new in iOS developing and the objective c. so i want to start with a simple app.
i'm trying to make an app for a play cards game that records the score each round. so it just adds up each team (two teams ) score. in the app interface there will be three buttons and two text fields to add the scores and a text view to see all the scores recorded.

so now i'm on the record method n i get a runtime error after pressing record in the iPhone simulator :

```
- (IBAction)record:(id)sender {
  //  NSString *slna = lna.text;
   // NSString *slhm = lhm.text;
    int x, y, resultx, resulty;
x  = [lna.text integerValue];
y  = [lhm.text integerValue];
resultx = 0;
resulty = 0;
resultx= resultx+x;
resulty= resulty+y;
alnashrah.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d      %d", resultx,resulty];
```

the error message i get : " Thread 1 : breakpoint 2.1 "

Comment: Since your "error message" includes something with breakpoints, try disabling breakpoints (short cut:command+Y).

Comment: Bad title.  This is not a problem with Objective C.

Answer (score 3):

IF that is all the information the console is telling us, this is not an error message, it means you added a breakpoint. Beside your code, you will see a gutter line, if you press it you can add breakpoints which are these blue arrow things. Here is an image:

[image: Breakpoint]

So to unselect the breakpoint, just click it or right click it and press delete.

Also to disable  breakpoints: command+Y or press the breakpoints select button at the top near the stop button and the scheme bar and the build status bar

Comment: okay id did that but now i get this one :
Thread 1:EXC_BREACKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0*0)

Comment: for this code :  @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }

Comment: Whats are u getting in console

Comment: 2012-05-13 01:39:34.412 sakkah[64201:f803] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x3514 of class 'ViewController' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
2012-05-13 01:39:34.415 sakkah[64201:f803] *** NSInvocation: warning: object 0x3514 of class 'ViewController' does not implement doesNotRecognizeSelector: -- abort
(lldb)

Comment: ahh ok there is a problem in your code, inside ViewController
Can you show all ur code in ViewController
There is a problem with a method: methodSignatureForSelector

Comment: also, if that still does not work, go to edit scheme, then select the run bar, then change LLDB to GDB

Comment: alright i got every thing working perfectly Except for the erase button,, which is basically an undo button.

Comment: I am so angry about how my app crashes because I accidentally clicked somewhere I wasn't supposed to. I hate xCode as an IDE. I love Apple and iOS, but stupid shit like this can get so frustrating. Thanks for the answer though, I'll never make this mistake again

Comment: @bwheeler96 Haha, Xcode is a great IDE, the best one you will find.

Comment: hahaha ya I think I'm just bitter about the small things like this. I'm starting to like it more and more, but at times it definitely feels unstable