# Random images error

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, uiimage, arc4random

I'm making an app that when you press a button it give you a random image. When I run it I don't get any error, but when I click on the button the app freeze and on xcode it says "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" at the end of this code right here:

```
-(void)changeLabel{

    progressView.progress += 0.15;

    if (progressView.progress == 1) {

        label.hidden = YES;

        progressView.hidden = YES;

        [timer invalidate];

        imagenesTest.hidden = NO;


         int randomNumber = arc4random() % 4;

        switch (randomNumber) {

            case 0:

                imagenesTest.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];

                break;
            case 1:

                imagenesTest.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];

                break;
            case 2:

                imagenesTest.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];
                break;

            case 3:

                imagenesTest.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"];
         default:
                break;
}
}
}
```

When I press a button it supposed to active a progress bar and then put the random image. It gives the error before the progress bar starts working. Here is the code I have for the button:

```
- (IBAction)scan:(id)sender {



    label.hidden = NO;

    imagenesTest.hidden = YES;



    progressView.hidden = NO;


    progressView.progress = 0;



    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(changeLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



}
```

When I click on the thread, it highlights me this

```
0x94feb6:  jmp    0x3ef05 
                  ; -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 4724
```

Am I doing something wrong with the code? Sorry if I didn't explain myself well, I started programming a some months ago

Thank you, Emilio

Comment: cross verify the name of IBOutlets, and check whether you are using the same name in .h file as well as xib file.

Comment: I checked everything a couple times and everything seems alright

Comment: It sounds like you've set a breakpoint. Do any show up in the breakpoints window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF that is all the information the console is telling us, this is not an error message, it means you added a breakpoint. Beside your code, you will see a gutter line, if you press it you can add breakpoints which are these blue arrow things. Here is an image:

So to unselect the breakpoint, just click it or right click it and press delete.

Also to disable breakpoints: command+Y or press the breakpoints select button at the top near the stop button and the scheme bar and the build status bar

Check my answer to this recent similiar question:
[iPhone app simple calculator - objective c error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568775/iphone-app-simple-calculator-objective-c-error/10568801#10568801)

UPDATE:

Can you put some `NSLog` that check if the image is valid and that methods are being called. Tell me your results!

`NSLog` is basically logging into the debugging console. So add `NSLog(@"test");` into your method and if it  gets printed into the console you know the method has been called

Also maybe put an `if` statement saying

```
if (image) {
NSLog(@"image is valid");
}
```

That statement's condition takes place only if `image` is non-zero/valid/initialized. Therefore

> image is valid

should be printed in the debugging console

Comment: Thanks, now it doesn't stop working. But I can't get the random images working, it just doesn't appear. I have a UIImageView on the nib file and the IBOutlet on the h file... everything seems be good

Comment: Thanks for your help and yes, it says in the console "Image is valid" I'm going to try making a new project, because I've testing stuff and maybe I screwed up something.. I don't really know

Comment: Alright, it is working now. I don't know why it didn't work before. Thanks :)